# , or ) expected in Jquery function call in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, internet-explorer

[image: i'm getting this error]

, or ) expected in Jquery function call in magento 2.
I'm getting this error in custom jquery file.

I'm getting this following error in internet explorer browser.
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: can you post the actual error in the browser console, It seems your code is all good

Comment: which editor use ???

Comment: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'   @fmsthird

Comment: Phpstorm @RkRathod

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is valid ES6 Javascript but Internet Explorer does not support ES6 (ECMAScript 2015), so you'll need to write the ES5 equivalent which looks something like this:

```
if (typeof entity === 'undefined') {
    entity = null;
}
```

Comment: @Ben_Crook . This is not about which version i'm using in editor. I'm getting this error in Internet explorer.

Comment: The same thing stands, you are writing ES6 Javascript when IE only supports ES5

Comment: If you are supporting IE you cannot use default values on arguments, you need to do what I've done in my answer and manually check if a value has been assigned. So check if it's `undefined` and if so you set it to null.

Answer (score 1):

> **Confige `JavaScript language version` In phpstrom**

Go to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript`

Then change `JavaScript language version` to `ECMAScript 6`

From the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) you can see there is still very limited support for default parameters. If you want to use default parameters I suggest looking into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Error is not coming in Phpstorm after changing the version. How to resolve this error in Internet Explorer?

Comment: what error in  Internet Explore ???

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: updated my answer